# AnyLogic: User Set Number Of Replications

Tags: anylogic, montecarlo

In a MonteCarlo experiment, I wish to allow a user to enter the number of Replications via an input box.  I have tried creating a variable linked to an input box and then referencing this in the "Replications per iteration" input box, but get an "invalid number" message.

Is there a way of using Java, say in the "Initial experiment setup" input box, to do this programmatically?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Hcd.png

Answer (score 0):

Some properties of elements and experiments (like "Replications per iteration") are just fixed user-entered values (not Java expressions) and thus you can't determine them programmatically.

The `setFixedReplicationsNumber` function exists on a Monte Carlo experiment (which is actually a Parameter Variation experiment technically --- it's just a wizard to create a pre-configured PV experiment).

However, this function doesn't actually work for your purposes; it's a setup only function so calling it (even in the "Initial experiment setup" action) is too late for it to change anything (and the Javadoc (as shown in the code autocomplete) states that, and that users shouldn't call it).

Only way I know to do this off the top of my head is using custom experiments (or possibly a programmatically-created ParameterVariation experiment) launched from, say, a Simulation experiment which has the UI you want in it. But that's pretty advanced. (Others may have time to explain this approach in more detail.)